# angularjs having different layouts without ng-view

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

In many applications you want to have different layouts (that are complely different from eachother)

an example of this could be:

```
login_layout.html
client_layout.html
admin_layout.html
```

So far i have only been able to find the most basic way to set a new view such as `ng-view=""`

However my idea is to build this property within each layout.

My question is how would you load the different layouts as the top layout around each individual view?

Comment: You can try ui-router or use ng-include

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as `ngView` is pretty basic in its implementation whereas ui-router allows you to do exactly what you're asking. You can define a view and then nest a view within it so that the outer view functions as a general wrapper and "sub sections" can be loaded within it as necessary with their own inner layout. Read up on it more [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views).

**Update:** Adding link to example.

The ui router site has examples of this and more but here is a [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview) to one of their plunkers demonstrating nesting views.

Comment: Hey :) i was also looking for this! is it possible that you could post an example of how it would be used?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, I've update the answer with a link to a plunker example from the angular ui router site

Comment: @ragmufin the example is where you change the view and not the entire HTML page do you know if this is possible?

Comment: In the example I posted it only changes the view if you click on Route 1 or Route 2 and then clicking "Show List" changes the nested view within that view.